# How to select features in a feature collection simultaneously row by row in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, feature-collection

I try to find a correlation between a linear trend of two NDVI time series before and after a specific day in time. And that I want to repeat (iterate/map?) for a lot of points globally distributed. This is the code @Daniel Well helped me with:

```
var conflicts = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([12.492297, 41.89024]), {conflictDate: '2010-01-01'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([12.453361, 41.902216]), {conflictDate: '1990-01-01'})
])

var startDate = '1989-01-01'
var endDate = '2013-12-16'

var timeSeries = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GIMMS/3GV0')
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .select(['ndvi'])
    .map(function (image) {
      return image.addBands(
        ee.Image(image.getNumber('system:time_start'))
          .subtract(ee.Date(startDate).millis())
          .divide(1000*3600*24) // days
          .int()
          .rename('t')
      )
    })

var conflictsWithSlopes = conflicts.map(addSlopes)
print(conflictsWithSlopes)
print('slope change stats', conflictsWithSlopes.aggregate_stats('slopeChange'))
// Other aggregate_*() functions...


function addSlopes(conflict) {
  var conflictDate = conflict.getString('conflictDate')
  var beforeSlope = getSlope(timeSeries, conflict, startDate, conflictDate)
  var afterSlope = getSlope(timeSeries, conflict, conflictDate, endDate)
  return conflict
    .set('beforeSlope', beforeSlope)
    .set('afterSlope', afterSlope)
    .set('slopeChange', afterSlope.subtract(beforeSlope))
}

function getSlope(timeSeries, conflict, startDate, endDate) {
  return timeSeries
    .select(['t', 'ndvi'])
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.linearFit())
    .select('scale')
    .reduceRegion({
      // If your conflict regions aren't points, 
      // you might want to use a mean or median reducer
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
      geometry: conflict.geometry(),
      scale: 8000
    })
    .getNumber('scale')
}
```

Now I would like to use conflict points (around 9000) and their corresponding dates (like in the example) stored in a FC [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/welp1992/Conflicts25_Date)
The conflict coordinates column is called "coordinate" and the date "date_start".

So far I have tried this:

```
var conflicts = conflicttable.select(['coordinate']);
var conflictDate = conflicttable.select(['date_start']);
```

and I get this error: 
*FeatureCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=000000000000000005a2): DateRange: Parameter 'start' is required.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (except for just picking up the conflict date with a different property name, `conflictDate -> date_start`) is that you have conflicts for dates where you have no imagery. You need to have some images both before and after your conflict date to calculate the two slopes. You can filter out conflicts outside of some date range like this:

```
var startDate = '1989-01-01'
var endDate = '2013-12-16'
var conflicts = ee.FeatureCollection('users/welp1992/Conflicts25_Date')
  .filterMetadata('date_start', 'greater_than', '1990-01-01')
  .filterMetadata('date_start', 'less_than', '2013-01-01')
  .limit(259)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7f08b9827f13c8ccde7b0c5bc7718525

Comment: Thank you for the help! Yes I thought about that too. If one of the time spans is less than one year, the slope will be quite big (positive or negative) and the sum will not say anything. I will play around till I find a reasonable time span. Besides that apparently I can only compute around 3500 points, than this error appears: <Earth Engine capacity exceeded>. I can devide the tasks, but is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: `Earth Engine capacity exceeded` is usually a temporary problem that goes away. You would typically see out of memory errors or computation timed out. If you're having problems, don't print the results in the code editor, just export them. You get more resources when processing in a background task.

Comment: Thanks, yes it worked after trying a few times. Also exporting as CSV file worked!